# Mount remotely and emulate an optical disk drive from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, optical-drive

## The problem

Recently, I've been copying some CDs/DVDs/Blu-rays I had laying back in some bookshelves at home from a Blu-ray player from a laptop which doesn't work. However, I can't put a portable optical blu-ray drive on my new laptop. I bought an ODD to USB3.0 adapter, but it keeps crashing after 2 minutes of copying, so I also bought an ODD to SATA adapter (passive, only pin remap and different connectors). Next, it would be cool to access it sometimes on another computer, without moving the drive everytime and open the case. For other laptops too.

## The perfect solution needed

I have a server that is powered on 24/24 and 7/7 but is too slow to convert videos and extract music in batch, so the plan is:

1. Put the drive on the server with the SATA adapter and start a  server app,

   With some driver on Windows, see the drive as being "native" by connecting the driver/client to the server and be able to extract original Blu-ray for example.

### My config

The server is under ArchLinux with the latest updates (to date), and I have Windows 10 on my laptop. Samba is a no-go solution, because it'll just expose "files", and not the RAW/block device that I need.

### What I found/tried

- **NBD**, but only works on Linux, and I don't see any way to make it works on Windows,
- And nothing more :(, the Disc Sharing feature of OS X looks too simplistic and is proprietary, maybe Windows, no Linux at all,
- You tell me ;)

Anyway, thanks you for your future answers !

Comment: Google how to set up [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) on Linux and Windows. Optical drives use basically SCSI over ATA.

Comment: Thanks ! I just configured iSCSI on my devices and it works perfectly ! This was a bit to hard to understand, especially on the Linux side though... Thanks !

Comment: Please write up what you did as answer and accept it, so the next person with the same problem knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dirkt, I setup my server as an iSCSI Target withing Arch Linux by installing targetcli-fb from AUR, enabling the target SystemD service and finally configuring everything with the targetcli utility.
On the Windows side, I fired up the iSCSI Initiator embedded in Windows, and configured everything. It then appeared as a native disk drive and worked quite good.
Unfortunately for some reason, a special command to the disk drive made a systematic kernel panic. It seem the LUN driver included in the mainstream Linux is not really stable for now... Or don't like special commands and doesn't want to deny them.

Anyway, if you want to share a HDD it should be OK !

Source: [iSCSI Target - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ISCSI_Target)